# Setting SCNNode.morpher causes crash when I try to write the SCNScene to file

Tags: cocoa, scenekit

OK so I am attempting to add an array of SCNGeometry to an SCNMorpher object and add this object to the root node on a scene and export the result to a DAE file.

For some reason, whenever I attempt to save the file I get a BAD_ACCESS error on the writeToURL call.

This only happens if I set the node.morpher property. It happens even if I set the morpher property to [[SCNMorpher alloc] init]] or to an instance with an empty array of targets.

This is on a Mac app.
My code:

```
NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int f=0; f<self.Animations[0].framesCount; f++) {
  SCNGeometry *frameGeo = [self MorphedModel:self.Animations[0] atFrame:f+1];
  SCNMaterial *framemat = [SCNMaterial material];
  framemat.diffuse.contents = texture;
  framemat.name = @"Dino Skin";

  frameGeo.firstMaterial = framemat;
  [frames addObject:frameGeo];
}
self.MorphedModels = [[SCNMorpher alloc] init];

self.MorphedModels.targets = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:frames];
node.morpher = self.MorphedModels;

SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];

NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Dino.dae"];
[scene writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:nil delegate:nil progressHandler:nil];
```

Any ideas? I'm clueless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. There isn't any documentation on this but it makes sense. You have to set one of the targets to a full weight (1.0f) on your SCNMorpher instance:

```
[self.MorphedModels setWeight:1.0f forTargetAtIndex:0];
```

Once I did this, everything saved correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that. You would think (and I expected) that any parsing errors should have been passed down to the progressHandler...